# Number of overlapping intervals over time

Tags: r, lubridate

Let's say I have a set of, partly overlapping, intervals

```
require(lubridate)
date1 <- as.POSIXct("2000-03-08 01:59:59")
date2 <- as.POSIXct("2001-02-29 12:00:00")
date3 <- as.POSIXct("1999-03-08 01:59:59")
date4 <- as.POSIXct("2002-02-29 12:00:00")
date5 <- as.POSIXct("2000-03-08 01:59:59")
date6 <- as.POSIXct("2004-02-29 12:00:00")
int1 <- new_interval(date1, date2)
int2 <- new_interval(date3, date4)
int3 <- new_interval(date5, date6)
```

Does anyone have an idea how one could construct a time series plot that provides, for every point in time, the number of overlapping intervals at that point?

So, for instance, to take the above example: For a given date in January 2000, the function I'm looking for would return the value "1" (the date is only within `int2`) while for a date in January 2001, it would return "3" (since that date is within `int1`, `int2` and `int3`). Etc.

Any ideas?

Comment: The IRanges package could prove helpful. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15235821/merge-overlapping-ranges-into-unique-groups/15235901#15235901) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3916195/finding-overlap-in-ranges-with-r) for a start.

Answer (score 5):

Here's one way using `foverlaps()` function using `data.table` package:

> Please install the development version 1.9.5 by following the [installation instructions](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation) as a bug that affects overlap joins on numeric types has been fixed there.

```
require(data.table) ## 1.9.5+
intervals = data.table(start = c(date1, date3, date5), 
                       end   = c(date2, date4, date6))

# assuming your query is:
query = as.POSIXct(c("2000-01-01 00:00:00", "2001-01-01 00:00:00"))
```

We'll construct the query data.table with both start and end intervals as well:

```
querydt = data.table(start=query, end=query) # identical start,end
```

Then we can use `foverlaps()` as follows:

```
setkeyv(intervals, c("start", "end"))
ans = foverlaps(querydt, intervals, which=TRUE, nomatch=0L, type="within")
#    xid yid
# 1:   1   1
# 2:   2   1
# 3:   2   2
# 4:   2   3
```

We first *set key* - which sorts the data.table `intervals` by the columns provided, in increasing order, and marks those columns as the key columns on which we want to perform the overlap join.

Then we use `foverlaps()` to find which intervals in `querydt` overlaps (falls *type=within*) with `intervals`. In this case, `querydt` consists of just points as start and end points are identical. This returns all matching indices (nomatch=0L removes all rows with no matches and which=TRUE returns indices instead of merged result) for those rows in `querydt` that falls within `intervals`.

Now all we have to do is to aggregate by `xid` and count the number of observations to get the count:

```
ans[, .N, by=xid]
#    xid N
# 1:   1 1
# 2:   2 3
```

Check `?foverlaps` for more info.

Comment: The upvoting patterns in SO is just amazing