# Consolidate rows based on date ranges

Tags: r, date, dataframe, data.table

I'd like to combine rows of a data frame such that the ranges described by a "start" and "end" column include all values from the original data set. There might be overlaps, repeats, and nested ranges. Some ranges might be missing.

Here's an example of the kind of data I'd like to collapse:

```
data = data.frame(rbind(
    c("Roger", 1,  10),
    c("Roger", 10, 15),
    c("Roger", 16, 17),
    c("Roger", 3,  6),
    c("Roger", 20, 25),
    c("Roger", NA, NA),
    c("Susan", 2,  8)))
names(data) = c("name", "start", "end")
data$start = as.numeric(as.character(data$start))
data$end = as.numeric(as.character(data$end))
```

The desired result would be:

```
name   start end
Roger  1     17
Roger  20    25
Susan  2     8
```

My attempt has been to expand out every item in the range for each row. This works, but then I'm not sure how to shrink it back. Additionally, the full dataset I'm working with has ~30 million rows and very large ranges, so this method is VERY slow.

```
pb <- txtProgressBar(min = 0, max = length(data$name), style = 3)
mylist = list()
for(i in 1:length(data$name)){
  subdata = data[i,]
  if(is.na(subdata$start)){
    mylist[[i]] = subdata
    mylist[[i]]$each = NA
  }
  if(!is.na(subdata$start)){
    sequence = seq(subdata$start, subdata$end)  
    mylist[[i]] = subdata[rep(1, each = length(sequence)),]
    mylist[[i]]$daily = sequence
  }
  setTxtProgressBar(pb, i)
}

rbindlist(mylist)
```

Comment: Maybe it's obvious but why is Roger appearing twice? and not in one row with start = 1 and end = 25?

Comment: @snoram Good question. Because Roger didn't have an 18 or 19, so the two records reflects the gap in his ranges.

Comment: Related: [collapse intersecting regions in R](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16957293/collapse-intersecting-regions-in-r) and [Merge Overlapping Ranges into unique groups](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15235821/merge-overlapping-ranges-into-unique-groups)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm guessing IRanges is much more efficient for this, but...

```
library(data.table)

# remove missing values
DT = na.omit(setDT(data))

# sort
setorder(DT, name, start)

# mark threshold for a new group
DT[, high_so_far := shift(cummax(end), fill=end[1L]), by=name]

# group and summarise
DT[, .(start[1L], end[.N]), by=.( name, g = cumsum(start > high_so_far + 1L) )]

#     name g V1 V2
# 1: Roger 0  1 17
# 2: Roger 1 20 25
# 3: Susan 1  2  8
```

*How it works:*

- `cummax` is the cumulative maximum, so the highest value so far, including the current row.
- To take the value excluding the current row, use `shift` (which draws from the prior row).
- `cumsum(some_condition)` is a standard way of making a grouping variable.
- `.N` is the last row of the group determined by `by=`.

The columns can be named in the last step like `.(s = start[1L], e = end[.N])` if desired.

---

**With date intervals**. If working with dates, I'd suggest the `IDate` class; just use `as.IDate` to convert a `Date`.

We can `+1` on dates, but unfortunately cannot `cummax`, so...

```
cummax_idate = function(x) (setattr(cummax(unclass(x)), "class", c("Date", "IDate")))

set.seed(1)
d = sample(as.IDate("2011-11-11") + 1:10)
cummax_idate(d)
#  [1] "2011-11-14" "2011-11-15" "2011-11-16" "2011-11-18" "2011-11-18"
#  [6] "2011-11-19" "2011-11-20" "2011-11-20" "2011-11-21" "2011-11-21"
```

I think this function can be used in place of `cummax`.

The extra `()` in the function are there because `setattr` won't print its output.

Comment: I would move `na.omit` to be applied after `setDT` to use eventually faster `na.omit.data.table` method.

Comment: @This is great. I'm actually using this for date ranges, but converting the dates to numeric and then back to dates works with this method and preserves the dates.

Comment: @Nancy Glad to hear it's working. I've added my ideas for how to handle dates, not sure if it'll be any more efficient than what you're doing, though, or even if it will work.