# Merging rows with overlapping values

Tags: r, merge, data.table, overlap

I've got a `data.table` that has UniqueID's for each row, an age column, and 2 columns with a confidence interval for the age. What I want to do is to merge rows that have an overlapping CI so the CI returned is the min/max of the overlap.

```
   ID   Age AgeMax AgeMin
1:  2 48073  49213  46933
2:  3 49002  49638  48366
3:  7 44297  44706  43888
```

The returned result for this example would then be:

```
ID  Age    AgeMax   AgeMin
2   48409   49638   46933
7   44297   44706   43888
```

As ID 2 and 3 have overlapping values in AgeMax and AgeMin. The AgeMax for ID == 2, is less than the AgeMax for ID == 3, but greater than the AgeMin for ID == 3 and therefore they overlap. ID 7 doesn't overlap with the other rows so it's returned as it was.

I actually don't mind what the `ID` and `Age` being returned is, as long as it's from one of the overlapping `ID`'s

My attempt is below, but I'm not getting the right results

```
library(data.table)
# sequence of years
step <- 10
window <- 30
startYear <- -60000+(0.5*window)
endYear <- 0-(0.5*window)
yrSeq <- abs(seq(startYear, endYear, step))

# Example DT
DT <- structure(list(ID = c(2L, 3L, 7L), Age = c(48073L, 49002L, 44297L
), AgeMax = c(49213L, 49638L, 44706L), AgeMin = c(46933L, 48366L, 
43888L)), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"
))

# split into a list to expand the CI's
s <- split(DT, DT$ID)

# Expand the CI's, to the nearest year in the seq
# merge back into a DT
d_seq <- rbindlist(lapply(s, function(x) {
      data.table(ID = x$ID, Yr = yrSeq[between(yrSeq, x$AgeMin, x$AgeMax)])}))

# remove duplicated years and return min and max years for each ID
d_seq <- d_seq[!duplicated(d_seq$Yr),]
d_seq <- d_seq[, .(AgeMin = min(Yr), AgeMax = max(Yr)), by = ID]

# merge with the original DT and select columns
DT <- merge(DT, d_seq, by = "ID")
DT <- DT[, c(1,2,5,6)]
```

Unfortunately, this isn't working as ID == 3 is being returned even though is overlaps with ID == 2 (as shown above) and now the AgeMin and AgeMax for ID == 2 doesn't cover the Age for that ID!

```
   ID   Age AgeMin AgeMax
1:  2 48073    46935    49205
2:  3 49002    49215    49635
3:  7 44297    43895    44705
```

I'm sure I'm overthinking this and that there must be a simple way that returns what I need, unfortunately I haven't been able to find any solutions.

I've already tried to modify the examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28938147/how-to-flatten-merge-overlapping-time-periods) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41747742/collapse-rows-with-overlapping-ranges).

Here is an extra example `data.table` to test on.

```
testDT <- structure(list(ID = c(54L, 57L, 58L, 60L, 61L, 62L, 64L, 180L
), Age = c(14219L, 13989L, 13883L, 13482L, 13403L, 13383L, 13340L, 
13994L), AgeMax = c(14343L, 14087L, 13972L, 13540L, 13465L, 13442L, 
13407L, 14083L), AgeMin = c(14095L, 13891L, 13794L, 13424L, 13341L, 
13324L, 13273L, 13905L)), row.names = c(NA, -8L), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a `data.table` solution

```r
library(data.table)
setDT(testDT)

testDT[order(AgeMin)
      ][, .(AgeMin=min(AgeMin), AgeMax=max(AgeMax)),
       by=.(group=cumsum(c(1, tail(AgeMin, -1) > head(AgeMax, -1))))]
#>    group AgeMin AgeMax
#> 1:     1  13273  13540
#> 2:     2  13794  14087
#> 3:     3  14095  14343
```

The key of this solution is getting the `group` of overlapping periods.

Let's say we have two ranges `p1` and `p2`. They have start and end named as `start1`,`end1`,`start2`，`end2`.

There are only two conditions where `p1` and `p2` are not overalpping.

1. `start1` > `end2`
   OR
2. `end1` < `start2`

Since we already ordered `Agemin` ascendingly, we only need to consider conditioon 1 only.
Then we can use `cumsum` to get the group indentifier.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need a combination of `data.table` and `igraph` as the overlaps might be chaining endlessly even though the last ID might have no overlap with the first ID in the chain.

Here is an option:

```
#find overlapping intervals using data.table::foverlaps
setkey(setDT(testDT), AgeMin, AgeMax)
d <- unique(foverlaps(testDT, testDT)[, .(x=pmin(ID, i.ID), y=pmax(ID, i.ID))])
    
#find clusters of IDs with overlapping intervals
library(igraph)
g <- graph_from_data_frame(d, directed=FALSE)
m <- setDT(stack(clusters(g)$membership))[, ind := as.integer(as.character(ind))]

#lookup grouping using update join
testDT[m, on=.(ID=ind), cls := values]

#output
testDT[order(ID), .(ID=ID[1L], Age=Age[1L], AgeMin=min(AgeMin), AgeMax=max(AgeMax)),
    cls]
```

output:

```
   cls ID   Age AgeMin AgeMax
1:   3 54 14219  14095  14343
2:   2 57 13989  13794  14087
3:   1 60 13482  13273  13540
```

---

edit:
Frank Zhang approach reminded me of David Aurenburg approach in [How to flatten / merge overlapping time periods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28938147/how-to-flatten-merge-overlapping-time-periods/28938694#28938694). Hence something like:

```
setDT(testDT)[order(AgeMin, AgeMax), g := 
    cumsum(c(0L, (shift(AgeMin, -1L) > cummax(AgeMax))[-.N]))
    ]

testDT[order(ID), .(ID=ID[1L], Age=Age[1L], 
        AgeMin=min(AgeMin), AgeMax=max(AgeMax)),
    g]
```

This should be faster.

Answer (score 0):

This solution is pretty readble and flexible, so adjust to your needs.

**sample data**

```
testDT <- structure(list(ID = c(54L, 57L, 58L, 60L, 61L, 62L, 64L, 180L
), Age = c(14219L, 13989L, 13883L, 13482L, 13403L, 13383L, 13340L, 
           13994L), AgeMax = c(14343L, 14087L, 13972L, 13540L, 13465L, 13442L, 
                               13407L, 14083L), AgeMin = c(14095L, 13891L, 13794L, 13424L, 13341L, 
                                                           13324L, 13273L, 13905L)), row.names = c(NA, -8L), class = c("data.table", 
                                                                                                                       "data.frame"))
```

**code**

```
library( data.table )
library( intervals )
#set testDT as data.table
setDT(testDT)
#assuming you want to merge all overlapping intervals to one long interval...
# create a table with joined intervals
# since inertvals need the min-col before max, we switch cols 3 and 4
DT.int <- as.data.table(
  intervals::interval_union( 
    intervals::Intervals( as.matrix( testDT[, 4:3] ) ) , 
    check_valid = TRUE ) )
#set colnames
setnames( DT.int, names(DT.int), c("AgeMin", "AgeMax" ) )
#add interval id's
DT.int[, interval_id := .I ][]
#    AgeMin AgeMax interval_id
# 1:  13273  13540           1
# 2:  13794  14087           2
# 3:  14095  14343           3

#now you can join the intervals back to DT, whatever/however you like
testDT[ DT.int, 
        `:=`( AgeMin.interval = i.AgeMin, AgeMax.interval = i.AgeMax, 
              interval.id = i.interval_id ),
        on = .( AgeMin <= AgeMax, AgeMax >= AgeMin ) ]
```

**output**

```
testDT

#     ID   Age AgeMax AgeMin AgeMin.interval AgeMax.interval interval.id
# 1:  54 14219  14343  14095           14095           14343           3
# 2:  57 13989  14087  13891           13794           14087           2
# 3:  58 13883  13972  13794           13794           14087           2
# 4:  60 13482  13540  13424           13273           13540           1
# 5:  61 13403  13465  13341           13273           13540           1
# 6:  62 13383  13442  13324           13273           13540           1
# 7:  64 13340  13407  13273           13273           13540           1
# 8: 180 13994  14083  13905           13794           14087           2
```

now process/summarise further as you like, for example: to get non-duplicated rows for `interval.id`...

```
testDT[ !duplicated( interval.id ), .(ID, Age, AgeMax, AgeMin) ]
#    ID   Age AgeMax AgeMin
# 1: 54 14219  14343  14095
# 2: 57 13989  14087  13891
# 3: 60 13482  13540  13424
```