# Combining overlapping ranges with a start and stop position in dataframe with other non-position values

Tags: r, dataframe, range

I am attempting to summarize blasting results such that I am trying to determine the full coverage of a contig (query) versus a database entry (subject). I have a dataframe with the usual outputs from blast but I am focused on the query length (qlen), length of query matching subject (length), query start position (qstart), and query stop position (qend), and query coverage (qcovhsp). This is an example of one query assembly/contig combination.

Reproducible Example

```
df = data.frame(qlen=c(100, 100, 100, 100, 100), length=c(10, 10, 15, 30, 10), qstart=c(1, 25, 30, 50, 70), qend=c(10, 34, 44, 79, 79), qconhsp=c(10, 10, 15, 30, 10))
```

| qlen | length | qstart | qend | qcovhsp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 10 | 1 | 10 | 10 |
| 100 | 10 | 25 | 34 | 10 |
| 100 | 15 | 30 | 44 | 15 |
| 100 | 30 | 50 | 79 | 30 |
| 100 | 10 | 70 | 79 | 10 |

I would like to summarize the above table such that overlapping ranges are merged, so if a range already covers the range from another row it absorbs that one (ex: row 4 absorbs 5) or if the ranges are overlapping that they are combined (rows 2 and 3 combine). And recalculates length and qconvhsp as needed.

| qlen | length | qstart | qend | qcovhsp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 10 | 1 | 10 | 10 |
| 100 | 20 | 25 | 44 | 20 |
| 100 | 30 | 50 | 79 | 30 |

I have the next script covered to summarize the above table to get the total query coverage (in this case 60%). I will be keeping assembly/contig combinations that have coverages over 70%. Using this to blast full assemblies against a database of complete plasmids and keep the contigs with 98% identity (already filtered) and 70% total converge.

Thank you for your time and help. Have not posted many questions, so I would appreciate any tips to improve as well.

I have attempted to search stack overflow for answers, but have not found any for my specific problem. Although [Collapse rows with overlapping ranges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41747742/collapse-rows-with-overlapping-ranges) does help with summarizing ranges, I am unsure how to apply within a table with multiple values besides start and stop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my most recent attempt to solve it which seems to work, open to suggestions for improvement. Lengths were wrong in my initial tables, forgot to add 1 to account for fact that length is not just subtraction for DNA positions, adjusted question accordingly.

Used the code from the hyperlinked question in my question and just rebuilt the table by either taking elements from original table or by recalculating values.

```
library(dplyr)

#Code from hyperlinked answer in question to create new dataframe based upon ranges
df_ranges <- df %>% 
  arrange(qstart) %>% 
  group_by(g = cumsum(cummax(lag(qend, default = first(qend))) < qstart)) %>% 
  summarise(qstart = first(qstart), qend = max(qend))

#Recalculated length
df_ranges$length = df_ranges$qend - df_ranges$qstart +1

#Saved qlen from original table
df_ranges$qlen = unique(df$qlen)

#Recalculated qcovhsp
df_ranges$qcovhsp = round(df_ranges$length/df_ranges$qlen*100, 0)

#Rearranged dataframe and removed extra row number column (g)
df_ranges <- subset(df_ranges, select = c("qlen", "length", "qstart", "qend", "qcovhsp"))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is likely applicable only to this quintet of rows as presented, and assumes first row will be included. We derive some indices make the summary df and still have to recalculate coverage

```
df_mtx = matrix(unlist(c(df[1, ], c(df[which.min(diff(df$qstart)), 1:3], df[which.min(diff(df$qstart)) +1, 4:5]), 
c(df[which.min(diff(df$qend)), 1:3], df[which.min(diff(df$qend)) +1, 4:5]))),
 nrow = 3, ncol = 5, byrow = TRUE)

df_mtx
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]  100   10    1   10   10
[2,]  100   10   25   45   15
[3,]  100   30   50   80   10

df_mtx[2:3, 5] = df_mtx[2:3, 4] - df_mtx[2:3, 3]
df_mtx
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]  100   10    1   10   10
[2,]  100   10   25   45   20
[3,]  100   30   50   80   30
```

Considering our indices

```
diff(df$qend)
[1] 25 10 35  0
diff(df$qend) == 0
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
df[diff(df$qend) == 0, ]
  qlen length qstart qend qconhsp
4  100     30     50   80      30
```

Rather than the convoluted, embedded c('s above, relying on diff == 0 that signals two overlapping ends, we could have just used df[diff(df$qend) == 0, ] for our third line.

So, clunky, mechanical, likely doesn't usefully scale beyond our five rows here. Also useful to keep in mind, indexing upon `diff` starts you at 2.

Comment: This does certainly help to solve the example, but I was looking for a more any use case instead of knowing what rows already need to be combined beforehand. And assuming the first row will be kept. Thank you very much for your time and effort in making this code though!

Comment: This is my most recent attempt to solve it. Lenths were wrong in my tables, forgot to add 1 to account for fact that length is not just subtraction for DNA positions.

df_ranges <- df %>% 
  arrange(qstart) %>% 
  group_by(g = cumsum(cummax(lag(qend, default = first(qend))) < qstart)) %>% 
  summarise(qstart = first(qstart), qend = max(qend))
df_ranges$length = df_ranges$qend - df_ranges$qstart +1
df_ranges$qlen = unique(df$qlen)
df_ranges$qcovhsp = round(df_ranges$length/df_ranges$qlen*100, 0)
df_ranges <- subset(df_ranges, select = c("qlen", "length", "qstart", "qend", "qcovhsp"))

Comment: If your commented code answers your needs, custom here would have you post it as an answer and accept it. Your's has a lot less fiddling round, or the `library(dplyr)` hides the fiddling. My problem was with row 1 and getting qcovhsp of 10 rather than 9, so I avoided with [2:3, ]. Some _might_ argue that 25->45 is 20, and 50->80 is 30, and I ran your code with df = rbind(df, df) same summary result. Put library(dplyr), your data, code, accept and let someone better than me help.

Comment: Hi Chris, aye aye, thanks for guidance, was unsure if I should (hopefully) answer my own question without others looking at code. Will adjust the question accordingly. Sorry that my initial tables caused issue. Thanks again for help!