# Find the intersection of grouped variables of a data frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe, merge, range, overlap

I have a data frame like this:

```
df <- data.frame(
  names = c(rep("cody", 10), rep("sam", 5)),
  year  = c(paste0("year",2000:2009), paste0("year",2000:2004))
)
```

I would like to get a resulting output like this:

```
df2 <- data.frame(
  names = c(rep("cody", 5), rep("sam", 5)), 
  year  = c(paste0("year",2000:2004), paste0("year",2000:2004))
)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15235821/merge-overlapping-ranges-into-unique-groups

Comment: Recommend `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` when creating data frames.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a base R method with `Reduce` and `intersect`.

```
dat[dat$year == Reduce(intersect, split(dat$year, dat$names)),]
```

which returns

```
  names     year
1   cody year2000
2   cody year2001
3   cody year2002
4   cody year2003
5   cody year2004
11   sam year2000
12   sam year2001
13   sam year2002
14   sam year2003
15   sam year2004
```

Here, we use `Reduce` to repeatedly feed arguments (the separate years for each name provided as a list using `split`) to `intersect`, which eliminates "non-matching" years until you end up with only those years that are available for all names.

Note that the year variable has to be a character vector, not a factor variable.

As a minor simplification, you could use `with` to reduce the `dat$` references:

```
dat[with(dat, year == Reduce(intersect, split(year, names))),]
```

**data**

```
dat <- 
structure(list(names = c("cody", "cody", "cody", "cody", "cody", 
"cody", "cody", "cody", "cody", "cody", "sam", "sam", "sam", 
"sam", "sam"), year = c("year2000", "year2001", "year2002", "year2003", 
"year2004", "year2005", "year2006", "year2007", "year2008", "year2009", 
"year2000", "year2001", "year2002", "year2003", "year2004")),
.Names = c("names", "year"), row.names = c(NA, -15L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 2):

You can group by year, then filter for those years that occur twice (or however many unique names you want):

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(year) %>% 
  mutate(name_count = n()) %>%
  ungroup() %>% 
  filter(name_count == 2) %>% 
  select(-name_count)

   names year    
   <fct> <fct>   
 1 cody  year2000
 2 cody  year2001
 3 cody  year2002
 4 cody  year2003
 5 cody  year2004
 6 sam   year2000
 7 sam   year2001
 8 sam   year2002
 9 sam   year2003
10 sam   year2004
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an option finding all the duplicates in the `year` column.

```
df[duplicated(df$year) | duplicated(df$year, fromLast = TRUE), ]
#    names     year
# 1   cody year2000
# 2   cody year2001
# 3   cody year2002
# 4   cody year2003
# 5   cody year2004
# 11   sam year2000
# 12   sam year2001
# 13   sam year2002
# 14   sam year2003
# 15   sam year2004
```